# Configuration of routes in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

i want to configure a new route, something like

```
http://localhost:4889/Home/Search
```

for this i am trying to configure in RouteConfig.cs as follows,

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "About",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

But its not working. Whenever i try to hit that route it will redirect me login route, am i missing something?
Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: Any other routes in your config? Show your entire config file. Any `[Authorization]` attributes on your actionmethods?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: This is my entire config class ` public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }`

Comment: ... That route has the exact same path your "About" route and redirects to "Login". What's unclear?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel so how to modify that? i want both the routes.What modifications i have to do?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel now i have changed that route to this, ` routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Search",
                url: "Search/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Seacrh", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );` Still its not working when i hit `http://localhost:4889/Search/Hello`

Answer (score -1):

Your route definition matches "Default" route, you probably haven't modified it and it's defined before your "About" route.

Or maybe you missed [Authorize] Attribute somewhere

I guess you want to delete this About route and just modify the Default one.

Comment: now i have changed that route to this, `routes.MapRoute( name: "Search", url: "Search/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Seacrh", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );` Still its not working when i hit http://localhost:4889/Search/Hello

Comment: "Hello" - is it the name of your action? Or is it a sort of identifier? Look into your Search action definition. What parameter does it accept? string id? Probably it is int id, and that's why that url can't map to your route